# Change voice of MaryTTS to French

Tags: java, text-to-speech, marytts

I started to use MaryTTS in a java project and it's working fine but with an english voice :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MaryConfigurationException, InterruptedException, SynthesisException {
        // init CLI options, args
        MaryInterface marytts = new LocalMaryInterface();
        Set<String> voices = marytts.getAvailableVoices();
        System.out.println(marytts.getAvailableVoices());
        marytts.setVoice(voices.iterator().next());
        AudioInputStream audio = marytts.generateAudio("Hello world");
        AudioPlayer player = new AudioPlayer(audio);
        player.start();
        player.join();
```

I need to set the voice to French.
So this is my pom.xml  :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.dfki.mary</groupId>
        <artifactId>voice-cmu-slt-hsmm</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.dfki.mary</groupId>
        <artifactId>marytts-lang-fr</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Those are my dependencies, so I have the maryTTS one, and the one that should bring me the french voice that I take on MavenSearch : https://search.maven.org/artifact/de.dfki.mary/marytts-lang-fr/5.2.1/jar

It seems like french is not implemented because if I do this :

```
Set<String> voices = maryTTS.getAvailableVoices();
for(String v : voices){
    System.out.println("Voice available: " + v);
}
```

This is what I get in console : **[cmu-slt-hsmm]**

What can I do more to set the voice in French ?

**EDIT** :
Ok so I am getting close to an answer, I downloaded two jar : **marytts.lang.fr** and **voice-enst-camille-hsmm** that I added to my project and if I do something like this :

```
        MaryInterface marytts = new LocalMaryInterface();   marytts.setLocale(Locale.FRENCH);
        marytts.setVoice("upmc-pierre-hsmm");
        AudioInputStream audio = marytts.generateAudio("Bonjour TEST TEST TEST ");
        AudioPlayer player = new AudioPlayer(audio);
        player.start();
        player.join();
```

It work, I have the french voice like I want BUT I also would like when I send a txt file, my program create a wav file and read it. This is working but only in english :

```
Options options = new Options();
        Option outputOption = Option.builder("o").longOpt(OUT_OPT).hasArg().argName("FILE").desc("Write output to FILE")
                .required().build();
        Option inputOption = Option.builder("i").longOpt(IN_OPT).hasArg().argName("FILE")
                .desc("Read input from FILE\n(otherwise, read from command line argument)").build();
        options.addOption(outputOption);
        options.addOption(inputOption);
        HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
        CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
        CommandLine line = null;
        try {
            line = parser.parse(options, args);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.err.println("Error parsing command line options: " + e.getMessage());
            formatter.printHelp(NAME, options, true);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // get output option
        String outputFileName = null;
        if (line.hasOption(OUT_OPT)) {
            outputFileName = line.getOptionValue(OUT_OPT);
            if (!FilenameUtils.getExtension(outputFileName).equals("wav")) {
                outputFileName += ".wav";
            }
        } else {
            System.err.println("Please provide an output wav filename.");
            formatter.printHelp(NAME, options, true);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // get input
        String inputText = null;
        if (line.hasOption(IN_OPT)) {
            String inputFileName = line.getOptionValue(IN_OPT);
            File file = new File(inputFileName);
            try {
                inputText = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Could not read from file " + inputFileName + ": " + e.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);
            }
        } else {
            try {
                inputText = line.getArgList().get(0);
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                // ignore
            }
        }
        if (inputText == null) {
            System.err.println("Please provide an input text.");
            formatter.printHelp(NAME, options, true);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // init mary
        MaryInterface mary = new LocalMaryInterface();


        // synthesize
        AudioInputStream audio = null;
        try {
            audio = mary.generateAudio(inputText);
        } catch (SynthesisException e) {
            System.err.println("Synthesis failed: " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // write to output
        double[] samples = MaryAudioUtils.getSamplesAsDoubleArray(audio);
        try {
            MaryAudioUtils.writeWavFile(samples, outputFileName, audio.getFormat());
            System.out.println("Output written to " + outputFileName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not write to file: " + outputFileName + "\n" + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

So to have it in french I just added :

```
mary.setLocale(Locale.FRENCH);
mary.setVoice("upmc-pierre-hsmm");
```

under

```
MaryInterface mary = new LocalMaryInterface();
```

But I have this error message when I try my app in terminal :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such voice: upmc-pierre-hsmm
        at marytts.LocalMaryInterface.setVoice(LocalMaryInterface.java:182)
        at de.dfki.mary.Txt2Wav.main(Txt2Wav.java:94)
```

EDIT : If I do this in my intellij and not in my terminal it's working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution to have maryTTS in french is to add those Jar in your project :
-https://gitlab.istic.univ-rennes1.fr/amucheri/avatar-beta2/-/blob/9f1027251cefa136f34e96d30789319aafec5625/lib/marytts-lang-fr-5.2.jar

this one to have the french local.

For the voices, you can add the jar or I think add this maven dependencies will also work :

-https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.dfki.mary/voice-enst-camille-hsmm/5.2

you can change the URL to find the voice you want.

By passing my arguments :

```
-i hello.txt -o hello.wav
```

In the arguments of my project in IntelliJ :
[image]

it work.

If someone know why it's working like this and not in my terminal I'm glad to hear it.